# Probability Question about Dice

Tags: probability

You toss two identical 6-sided dies, you get a dollar if the difference between the outcomes is 4 , zero otherwise. What is the fair value of a ticket to play this game? The fair value of a ticket is the mean reward from playing this game.

So I know I have to find the possibility that the difference between outcome is 4.
So I thought of all the cases that happens:

- 1 5
- 1 6
- 2 6

Are these all the cases? So wouldn't the fair value be 3/36?

Comment: the difference between 1 and 6 is 4?

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear whether the difference has to be exactly 4 or $\geq 4$. No matter what what interpretation is true you should carry in mind that you have two distinct dice, so $(2,6)$ and $(6,2)$ are different outcomes.

Therefore if the difference has to be exactly 4 you have 4 possible outcomes.

Comment: How come 1,5 and 5,1 are not two different outcomes? So in total, shouldn't there be 6 outcomes?

Comment: They arevdifferent. Therefore if the difference should be exactly 4 you have four options. It it has to be 4 or more then you indeed have 6 options.